# Creating a new YT.Player after onYouTubeIframeAPIReady

Tags: javascript, iframe, video, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I have a page that has multiple Youtube videos on it. I am basically trying to add some controls to the page that lets a user click next/back and go through the videos. However I am having trouble creating new YT.Player objects after onYouTubeIframeAPIReady is called. Setting up the first player works fine:

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('first-id', {});
}
```

When the next button is pressed, I try and get the next video with the same code:

```
player = new YT.Player('second-id', {});
```

If log this new player to the console it seems to work, because it shows an object with all the appropriate functions, however when I try and call one I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Also, I have seen some solutions that suggest pre-creating and the YT.Players in onYouTubeIframeAPIReady, but that will not work for me because I need to dynamically load more videos later.